# Throwing newUserError in getData() function

Tags: google-apps-script, looker-studio

I am currently building a data connector but would like to throw and error out to the user if the date range they have provided is not supported by my API endpoint (we don't have data for more than 90 days). I looked through the documentation and found this: https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/error-handling#user-facing-errors

And copied the code example exactly and tried to run it but my project still isn't showing the error dialog box back to the user.

I've also taken a look at how other people implement this in this repository (https://github.com/googledatastudio/community-connectors) but still can't see an issue with what I wrote.

```
function getData(request) {
    try {
        var dataSchema = getDataSchema(request);
        var data = lookupRequestData(request, dataSchema);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('pre throw');
        // throw Error('some error!');
        cc.newUserError()
            .setDebugText('Error fetching data from API. Exception details: ' + e)
            .setText('There was an error communicating with the service. Try again later, or file an issue if this error persists.')
            .throwException();

        console.log('post throw');
    }

    return {
        schema: dataSchema,
        rows: data
    };
}
```

I can see both the pre throw and post throw strings in my log but there is still no error message being displayed. Just wondering if someone might be able to offer a bit of advice for other things to try.

Thanks

Comment: I experienced something similar. Seems to be a problem with running V8. Initially the error would not be thrown in V8 but would work when V8 was disabled. Seems like recently they fixed the error being thrown in V8, but now the messages to user or admin don't show. Things work as expected when V8 is disabled.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue 2 years later, my community connector manifest is also V8